# Plot to visualize comparison of power analysis

Tags: data-visualization, statistical-power

I did two power analysis dependent of the same variables regarding two similar methods (method X and Y). The data are represented like :

```
  A  B   C  powerX  powerY
100  1  10     0.3     0.1
200  1  10     0.5     0.2
300  2  10     0.9    0.25
```

where I varied variable A, B and C in my simulation in order to compute powerX and powerY.

I was wondering the best way to visualize such data in a plot in order to show that method X is "more" powerfull than method Y.

FYI it seems that one variable has a bigger effect on both power output than the other variables. Thus I was thinking to plot the power on the Y-axis and this variable of interest on the x-axis. Put different colors for powerX and Y and different point/line shapes for the other variables.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to say a little more about what A, B, and C are, and what you're interested in showing. I feel this question shouldn't be too difficult to answer, but I can't figure out what you want to plot power against.

Comment: Why need any graph when this table does the job already?  .3 > .1, .5 > .2, and .9 > .25... I don't think people need the graph to conclude that X is more powerful than Y.